# Why is the method attribute removed from <form>?

Tags: forms, 8

I work on submitting form via Drupal's Mail API. I want to pass all data with POST method. While I add this parameter to my form it disappear after rendering.

Before rendering:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ current_path }}">
  [...]
</form>
```

After rendering the method is removed:

```
<form action="http://localhost/drupal/contact" data-drupal-form-fields="">
  [...]
</form>
```

Is there any other approach to get the POST method instead of default which is GET?

Comment: How are you generating the form? Are you using the Form API? The default method is `POST` when using the Form API. Post your code.

Comment: @mradcliffe From is written just in twig. It's not created programically.

Comment: Why are you not using Form API?